# How to make SSL-Requests with AWS-Lambda-Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a AWS-Lambda function that gots triggered after a file was placed into an S3-Bucket.

This is my lambda-function:

```
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {

 var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
 var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

 var newKey = key.split('.')[0].slice(8);

 var url = 'https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/api/messages/'+newKey+'/processingFinished'
 console.log("URL:" + url)

  http.get(url, function (result) {
    console.log('!!!! Success, with: ' + result.statusCode);
    context.done(null);
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error, with: ' + err.message);
    context.done("Failed");
  });
};
```

In CloudWatch Logfiles i see complaints that https is not supported:

```
2017-07-27T10:38:04.735Z    8428136e-72b7-11e7-a5b9-bd0562c862a0    Error: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"
at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:54:11)
at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
at Object.exports.get (http.js:35:21)
at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:18:8)
```

But the listed URL can be opened with any webbrowser. The Server accepts SSL and the whole API is working per SSL.

Why is AWS denying SSL-Requests? How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the node documentation: (https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)

HTTPS is the HTTP protocol over TLS/SSL. In Node.js this is implemented as a separate module.

Use

```
http = require('https');
```